# 2 eclipse installations 1 ADT install

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

Is there a way to have 2 installations of eclipse but 1 installation of ADT? I'm trying to save hard drive space, and thought I would ask. Thanks.

Comment: Really don't care anymore, I went ahead and re-downloaded ADT to the new eclipse install.

Answer (score 1):

You should just download the plugin through the first installation of Eclipse and copy the plugin into second Eclipse's plugin directory.

The point is to have only one folder for SDK (just setting the SDK path in ADT configuration panel) to save space (and Android Emulator Settings).

Answer (score 0):

ADT is an Eclipse plug-in.  You can have as many Eclipse installations as you like and choose to add ADT to any or all of them.  Note that RUNNING two ADT instances at the same time will confuse adb and generate a bunch of console warnings.